# Which method is used to store an object in the session?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

Which method is used to store an object in the session?

Please give me answer from given options.

1. setValue
2. putObject
3. setSession
4. setAttribute

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking... Give more context...

Comment: Sounds like someone is taking a test... lol

Answer (score 0):

You can use setAttribute method to store an object in the session

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
Object obj = new Object();
session.setAttribute("object", obj);
```

and after setting your attribute by using session, use following to access it in the JSP,

```
${sessionScope.object}
```

or

```
<%= session.getAttribute("object")%>
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to use: [javax.servlet.HttpSession.setAttribute()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 
session.setAttribute("sessionparam", paramValue)
```